# Citation of multiple webpages of same domain

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to cite multiple subpages of the same domain like [this one](http://cs231n.github.io).
When citing multiple passages of a book, I just need one bibliography entry which I can cite on multiple occasions specifying the page in the reference: ... [3, p. 107f.]

The given website has a book like structure with multiple chapters. If I want to cite multiple websites from this same domain (like http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/ and http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/), do I have to cite each subpage with an individual bibtex entry or is there a possibility to use some sort of collection type, and reference the subpages similar to chapters or pages like: ... [4, Optimization]?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand the question. Are you asking about the implementation, or the citing process?

Comment: @Johannes_B First about the process. If I have to cite every subpage as a website, I know how to do that. If one can cite them as one reference, I would be glad if you could provide a short implementation example.

Comment: If you cite one website, you have to add an entry in the database to have an entry in the document. If you don't need to cite the subpages explicitely, you don't need to add them to the bibliography, hence you don't need to bother collecting them. I still do not understand the question. Please edit it by clarifying. And correct the spelling mistake in the title.

Comment: @Johannes_B. I hope I could clarify the question

Comment: I would normally cite each sub page individually. Unlike for chapters and pages in a book or article it might be nontrivial to navigate from the main page to the sub page. You could of course only cite items as "[4, Optimization]" but then your readers would have to figure out what this refers to and you would probably not get a link to the subpage in your bibliography. ... What bibliography/citation package and which style do you use?

Comment: Note that the theoretical question of "should I only have one entry for the main page or several entries for the subpages in my bibliography" is not a TeX-nical question and as such probably borderline off-topic here. You may have a better chance asking it over at https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I use bibtex with the plainnat style at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would normally use a separate `@incollection` entry for each chapter of a `@collection` work (where the chapters are written by different authors) to give credit to each author properly, I would usually go for only one `@book` entry when the entire work is written by the same set of people and would not add bother with an `@inbook` for each chapter.

If people can get hold of the book a `@book` entry refers to, they can normally locate each chapter and page number easily, so [3, p. 107] is easily located.

On the other hand if [2] refers to http://cs231n.github.io/,

> [2, Optimization] (http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/)

is not as always as easily and naturally located (of course people know how to search on a page, but ...). So if you don't cite too many different subpages I would cite each subpage individually. This has the additional advantage that there is a direct link to each page that you cite in the bibliography. Of course you may feel that your bibliography is cluttered up with several very similar entries if you cite many subpages.

If there is a natural way to extract the full link for each subpage from the postnote argument you give, there might be a way to automate linking the postnote of a main-page citation directly to the subpage. But I doubt that that would be useful in printed documents ...